# Storage optimization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

On peak connections, NFS server seems to be unresponsive and takes a while to respond to basic commands like "ls" on the client side.

The entry in fstab

```
serverip:/home/media/  /home/media/archive  nfs      tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,rw,soft,intr,noatime,x-gvfs-show
```

This server is used only to read files from. Both server and client are working and responding fine if I log in via ssh. No useful info in syslog.

I suspect the number of files being retrieved and read maybe over 5,000 in peak periods. What can be causing NFS to be that slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS happens over the network, which is the biggest potential bottleneck. More load means more requests for data over the network and you might be overloading your switches or routers. Maybe the network isn't the problem, could be IOPS on your underlying storage. There are many ways to fix this issue.

This question would be better if you have some data about the network (difficult) or data about IO on the NFS host (easy). Try posting the output of `vmstat 1 60` during peak load.

This question is titled wrong because this is really a network question or storage optimization question.

Comment: procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  4 200184 174324  25796 15898520    0    0  1023    10    0    0  0  0 98  1  0

 0  3 200196 194112  25788 15891760    4   12 36360    12 13365 3651  0  1 76 23  0

 1  2 200196 175864  25788 15910580    0    0  7068    32 13523 2899  0  0 85 15  0